# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement42 cannot be cast to org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement

Tags: java, spring, derby

I want to create my first project connected with the apache-derby.

```
public Circle getCircle(int circleId){

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

     conn = dataSource.getConnection();

    **PreparedStatement ps =     (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM circle where id = ?"); 
     ((java.sql.PreparedStatement) ps).setInt(1,circleId);
    Circle circle = null;
    ResultSet rs =  ((java.sql.PreparedStatement) ps).executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        circle = new Circle(circleId,rs.getString("name"));
        }**
rs.close();
    ((Connection) ps).close();
return circle;
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
finally{
    try{
    conn.close();
    }catch (SQLException e){}
}
    }


public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

}

dataSource is defined as bean in my .xml file. Using Spring or not i have an error connected with the prepared statement :

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement42 cannot be cast to org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement
    at JdbcDemo.dao.JdbcDaoImpl.getCircle(JdbcDaoImpl.java:42)
    at JdbcDemo.JdbcDemo.main(JdbcDemo.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement42 cannot be cast to org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement
    at JdbcDemo.dao.JdbcDaoImpl.getCircle(JdbcDaoImpl.java:30)
    ... 1 more**

Could someone can help me ? I can add other class but i think probem is located in this class. I am using apache 10.12.1.1. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the wrong import for `PreparedStatement`. Your import should be:

```
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
```

There should **not** be any import for `org.apache.derby.iapi.sql.PreparedStatement`, this is not something you should be using here.

You do not need any casts in your code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM circle where id = ?"); 
ps.setInt(1, circleId);
Circle circle = null;
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After right import i have next problem:       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement42 cannot be cast to java.sql.Connection
 at JdbcDemo.dao.JdbcDaoImpl.getCircle(JdbcDaoImpl.java:43)
 at JdbcDemo.JdbcDemo.main(JdbcDemo.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement42 cannot be cast to java.sql.Connection
 at JdbcDemo.dao.JdbcDaoImpl.getCircle(JdbcDaoImpl.java:39)
 ... 1 more

Comment: Your `((Connection) ps).close()` is completely wrong. `ps` is a `PreparedStatement` not a `Connection`, just call `ps.close()`. You should not have to do any casts on SQL operations.